# When did the windows command line get the pipe (|)?

Tags: windows, command-line, pipe, ms-dos

I freely admit I have very little experience with the Windows cli but I seem to recall that DOS had no pipe (or redirect for that matter, but I may well be wrong, it's been a while).

I have seen some answers on this site that use the Unix pipe (`|`) character to pass information from one command to another. Is this something the Windows cli has added relatively recently? Is it a part of the normal Windows shell? Was it always there and I just did not know it? Did DOS have it?

In summary, can someone give me a *short* history of piping in the windows command line?

Comment: Well, the Windows command processor has been hosed since the beginning.  The pipe, I couldn't say for sure.  I think it sorta came and went a few times in specific contexts.

Comment: Been using DOS since I came off of CP/M and migrated over to IBM XT which would have been DOS 2.0. It's always been there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been there since IBM's PC DOS 2, [from what this page says](http://www.os2museum.com/wp/?page_id=630)

> The UNIX concepts implemented in DOS 2.0 were:
>
> ```
> Hierarchical directories
> Redirection (pipes)
> Background execution (daemons)
> ```

DOS / Windows uses the | pipe, >, >>, <, and << for redirection.

Powershell also uses the pipe heavily, where something like:

```
get-Something "C:\Program Files" | $_.Attribute | Out-File H:\MyInfo.txt
```

Comment: Wow. The sudden jump to Powershell is so jarring. Why? It seems utterly irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

I know the pipe and redirection was available since DOS 5.  See this [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=fGvWAAAAMAAJ&q=pipe%20dos%205&dq=pipe%20dos%205&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LuR1UZjcJ4zi4AP6uoCoDQ&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAQ).

Found a reference to piping and redirection in DOS 2.0 [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=yy8EAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA44&dq=pipe%20ms%20dos%204&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lOR1UbzGI7f54APav4CYBw&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=pipe%20ms%20dos%204&f=false).

So its definitely been around for a while...